# C++, assigning value to vector::end?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Let's say I have a vector v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. I would like to cut the last two elements, so I thought I'd do something like

```
v.end() = v.begin() + 3;
```

Let's take this snippet:

```
std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5};
std::cout << *(v.end()-1) << std::endl;
v.end() = v.begin() + 3;
std::cout << *(v.end()-1) << std::endl;
```

This prints 5 in both cases. Why is that? If vector::end returns an iterator, isn't it an rvalue? If so, the code shouldn't compile at all. If it's an lvalue, why won't the end iterator point to the element `v.begin() + 3`?

Comment: If you want to know whether you can assign to an rvalue, you should use a less confusing example. If you want to know how to "cut the last two elements" from a vector, then maybe you can drop the rvalue stuff. The two issues get in the way of each other and make the question unclear.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's a not entirely fair remark. You have to assume someone with a question doesn't have full understanding of the problem, that's after all why they ask. If you're at the C++ level that you come up with the code above, then it's not reasonable to expect you know the finer points about lvalues and rvalues. So you may see it fail, and start reasoning about what happens, and end up with the question above. And considering it's real compilable code, with expected and actual outcomes, I'd say it's proper for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

`std::end()` returns an iterator which points to the element *after the last one*. It can be only used as a reference (e.g. to compare another iterator to it), attempting to use it's value is undefined behavior.

That being said, this code `v.end() = v.begin() + 3;` is just repositioning the copy of the iterator that you got from the vector, it doesn't modify the vector itself.

Consider using one of [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) overloads to chop a part of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `v.end()`, a new iterator object is returned. This is an rvalue, but you can still change its value, but that does not have any effect on the container, your `v`.
If you want to erase something from the vector, use e.g. `vector::erase()`.

Comment: I think you mean it is an rvalue.

Comment: Hm, no? It is an object (type iterator), it occupies memory, you can assign something to it --> it is an lvalue.

Comment: It is an rvalue. `v.end()` is an rvalue expression (you can check that easily by writing  couple of functions, `void foo(const vector<int>::iterator&);` and `void foo(vector<int>::iterator&&)` and see which one overload resulution picks up.)

Comment: I guess R or L values is too simple for C++. what about Xvalue?

Comment: @AdrianMaire It is not an xvalue. It anything, it would be a prvalue. It is  still an rvalue, and definitely not an lvalue. So I find the up-votes to this answer both mystifying and disappointing. See this summary of  [value catagories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Comment: Okay, changed it to rvalue.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I understand that non-reference return are usually PR-values, but then, why is the statement `v.end()=...` not triggering an error?. Note: upvoting is only up to me

Comment: @AdrianMaire Simply because C++ allows it (before C++11, there used to be advice to return `const` values if one wanted to avoid modifying rvalues, but that has been dropped because it would prevent move semantics.)

Comment: @juanchopanza: `[]()->auto{ return 42;}() = 3;` trigger an compilation error because it is a PR-value.  `[v]()->auto{ return v.end();}() = v.begin();` do not (and it is not before C++11, but since C++14). The same case apply to any XValue returned by a function.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I made a typo in one of my earlier comments. You can modify rvalues of user defined types, but not for built-ins.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign the end iterator like that you need to erase.

```
v.erase(v.begin() + 3, v.end());
```